# One quartz expression for a job executing N times a day

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

So for example if I want to execute a job at 3:11:00 ,16:27:00 and 18:32:00 . Is it possible via single CRON expression in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. With standard CRON expressions you can either express running at different minutes of a single hour (`"0 11,27,32 3 * * ?"` - 3:11, 3:27, 3:32) or different hours at the same minute (`"0 11 3,16,18 * * ?"` - 3:11, 16:11, 18:11). But combining them (`"0 11,27,32 3,16,18 * * ?"`) will cause the expression to trigger three times on every hour (3:11, 3:27, 3:32, 16:11, 16:27...) - not what you want.

What you can do (and it's a legitimate solution) is defining one job and attaching three different triggers to it:

```
0 11  3 * * ?
0 27 16 * * ?
0 32 18 * * ?
```

Comment: Yeah that's true defining three triggers would solve the purpose . I was just thinking to avoid it , because I think that's not efficient .

Comment: @AmanChandna: well, as long as you don't have hundreds of thousands of triggers performance should not be an issue. Performance is more impacted by the number of concurrently running jobs.